# Cache HTTP response despite "no-cache" header in response

Tags: rest, http, caching, https, cache-control

My backend is making requests to a third-party REST API. I wish to cache requests to avoid hitting their rate limit. However, the third-party API is returning headers which instruct my caching layer (RFC 7234 compliant) not to cache. Is there any standards compliant way to instruct my caching layer to ignore directives provided in the response?

My backend is in Node.js and the caching layer I've tried is [cacheable-request](https://github.com/lukechilds/cacheable-request). I'm making requests with `Cache-Control: public, max-stale=900` header with the intention of allowing stale data to be served for 15 minutes. This works if I invoke an API which returns no cache-related response headers. However the real third-party API returns the following headers:

```
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 13:53:07 GMT
pragma: no-cache
vary: Accept-Encoding
```

And this seems to prevent my caching layer from kicking in.

The solution needs to be redundant and deploy-able in Kubernetes. I'm okay serving stale data as long as I can invalidate it whenever users make mutations or I receive an event hook from the third-party. I expect to find a solution which is fairly generic and does not require me to truly replicate and persist the third-party data structure in my own backend.

Answer (score 0):

As `cacheable-request` accepts any `http.request` API compatible method, you can make your own `http.request` compatible method, strip `cache-control` header, and wrap that method in `cacheable-request`.

Example code would look like:

```
const http = require('http');
const CacheableRequest = require('cacheable-request');

let withCacheHTTPRequestWrapper = function() {
  let originalCallback = arguments[arguments.length-1];

  let parameters = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arguments.length-1; i++) {
    parameters.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  let stripCacheHeaderCallback = function(res) {
    delete res.headers['cache-control'];
    // need to remove cache-control from res.rawHeaders too
    originalCallback(res);
  };
  parameters.push(stripCacheHeaderCallback);

  return http.request.apply(this, parameters);
};

// Example below
let req = withCacheHTTPRequestWrapper('http://example.com', function(response){
  // no "cache-control" in response now.
});
req.end();

// Wrap with cacheable-request
const cacheableRequest = new CacheableRequest(withCacheHTTPRequestWrapper);
```